# Android ADB fails to display devices on 2011 Macbook Pro

Tags: android, macos, adb

Just began working on a new 2011 Macbook Pro only to find ADB cannot see any of my devices. This occurs under Eclipse in DDMS and when I run `./adb devices`.

I have found some discussion of this saying there are intermittent issues in OS X 10.6.6 with problems seeing Android devices but this seems to be different as all of my devices are mountable via USB.

I see the exact same behavior running Windows 7 in Virtualbox, Apple support on this issue is non existent as they insist it is Android's problem.

The devices I have encountered this problem with include:
Sony Xperia mini X10
Motorola Droid
HTC Droid Eris
Samsung Galaxy Tab

Could this be a hardware problem on my new Macbook or am I dealing with something related to OS X?

Either way I may have to trade for a Windows laptop :-(

**updated March 27 2011
Have now tried a full Bootcamp installation of Windows 7 complete with all the Apple provided drivers - same result

resorting to powered USB hub didn't help either

The device appears as Android Phone under System Profiler but remains invisible to ADB, mounting works fine.

Comment: I've been using a new 2011 MacBook Pro for a few weeks and haven't run into this.  The Motorola Droid is the only device I've used that's also on your list, but it works fine for me.  I transfered everything from my old MBP so I'm not running the latest revision of the SDK.

Comment: I just tried installing an older SDK (android-sdk- mac_x86-1 .6_r1) and am seeing the same problem, am feeling more burned by this than any previous tech purchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution, seems the tethering software I had installed on the macbook was interfering with ADB:
http://www.intohand.com/blog/?p=116

Applying the fix made it "just work" again:

```
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
```