# Android: Cannot See Sony Tablet S in Eclipse Device Chooser

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, device

I have an app that's running on Android 2.1  I want to keep one code base and declare different folders for different resolutions for Android 3.2 tablets.

I've read this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
and this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up

The problem is that when I "Run" in Eclipse to Build/Compile/Run, it does not show the Sony Tablet S.

- Yes I have USB Debugging enabled on the Sony Tablet S
- Yes I have loaded this app to a phone before (Samsung Galaxy S II Skyrocket) and the Skyrocket shows in the Device Chooser
- Yes my Android SDK / AVD and Eclipse ADT should be up to date, I JUST updated it and even restarted the computer.
- Yes I've tired using different USB cables/ports (my Skyrocket works fine with this app)
- my target OS is Android 2.1 ... but all I wanted to do was make the UI compatible with Android 3.2 or a 10" tablet

I'm using a Mac.

-Faul

Comment: I am on OSX, and most of the time adb finds my devices. There are times when this does not work. For example, the Kindle Fire is not automatically detected on OSX. I have to open up my ~/.android/adb_usb.ini and add 0x1949, then kill and restart adb server. Maybe Sony has published a usb identifier that must be manually added as well?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this line to your ~/.android/adb_usb.ini file:

```
0x054c
```

Comment: vi ~/.android/adb_usb.ini  from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

This really is nothing to do with your app and is strictly that your computer isn't finding the device for some reason. See these other [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680637/mac-os-x-10-6-6-and-adb-devices-fails-to-list-android-devices) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412539/android-adb-fails-to-display-devices-on-2011-macbook-pro). Useful suggestions from among them are:

- Set your device to charge only USB mode
- Make sure EasyTether is not installed on your Mac.

Hopefully your problem can be fixed with one of these.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed drivers?
if not
http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Comment: From what I experienced, Macbook's do not need the drivers (it also says you can skip the driver installation in the Android Dev Guide).  Thanks though!